# Calculated Field error involving aggregates

Tags: average, tableau-api, aggregation, standard-deviation, calculated-field

**Problem:** The sheet has a calculated field named 'Average % Delta' and the field is required at date level.
On using the average function to figure out the average value of the calculated field, it throws a[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nouNs.png)n error. (an aggregate function cannot be aggregated further)
Is there any way around this error?
The calculations should hold for multiple selections in the filter too.

Similar error repeats while trying to find the standard deviation too.

link to tableau workbook : 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jtpy9fu0UvinMz-56dI5_je8m7AZ-jnp

Comment: As the error says you cannot take an aggregate of  an aggregate.  Ex: AVG(SUM([Number of Records]))  Please post your definition of the [Delta % Transactions]

Comment: My problem involves selecting multiple filters (eg: both town and village), though in the workbook i have limited it to single filter. In such a case, i would have to use [sum(control active)/sum(control base)] for 'control % Transactors'.

Similar for 'test % Transactors'.

'Delta % Transactors' is calculated as the difference between these two aggregates, which is populated at a daily level. Trying to find the std deviation of this field throws the error.

 

to put it simple, i need to calculate the standard deviation of a calculated field, which is an aggregate by itself

Comment: Depending on your visual you can probably use a table calculation like WINDOW_STDEV(metric).  Alternatively you can use an LOD expression in your first calculation, 'Delta % Transactions', to fix that aggregation to a particular dimension(s).  Then when you attempt to take a further aggregation like Std,  you shouldn't get an error.  The following is a detailed article about LOD's, nested LOD's at the end will likely solve your problem https://boraberan.wordpress.com/2015/01/30/whats-new-in-tableau-9-0-part-2-level-of-detail-expressions/